# how to define size function in Euclidean domain

Tags: ring-theory, integral-domain

I was reading about examples of Euclidean domains and their proofs. I encountered one problem on how to define size function for various Euclidean domains.
For example

in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ size function will be $a^2+b^2$

Similarly for $\mathbb{Z}[(-2)^{1/2}]$ will be $a^2+2b^2$ why can't I define it as $a^2+b^2$ because it will also be from $R-\{0\} \rightarrow N $.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want your size function to be multiplicative, so you need something like $$a+kb\to (a+kb)(a-kb)$$
where $k=\sqrt{-2}$ or whatever.

---

Example:
Set $x=1+\sqrt{-2}, y=1-\sqrt{-2}$.

Your size function gives $|x|=1^2+1^2=2, |y|=1^2+(-1)^2=2$.  However $xy=1-(-2)=3$, so your size function gives $|xy|=3^2=9$.  This is not multiplicative, since $2\cdot 2\neq 9$.

The standard size function gives $|x|=1^2+2(1^2)=3=|y|$, and $|xy|=9$.  Note that $3\cdot 3=9$, as desired.

Comment: But what is the issue with writing it as $a^2+b^2$ that also satisfies the necessary requirement of size function i think